# Know if MainApp is launched by HelperApp

Tags: cocoa, sandbox, launching-application

I am really stuck here with a simple task, but still cannot get it working.

I've managed to implement 'LaunchAtLogin' feature with the HelperApp as described in [this article](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/).
But my application should react differently on **launch-by-helper-app** and **launch-by-user** actions. So my task now is to have some kind of flag indicating that MainApp was launched by HelperApp.

I know there are many similar questions, but still none of the solutions works for me. Sandbox seems to cut all the parameters I am trying to send to the MainApp.

Here what I have tried:

```
- [NSWorkspace - launchApplicationAtURL: options: configuration: error:]
 - [NSWorkspace - openURLs: withAppBundleIdentifier: options: additionalEventParamDescriptor: launchIdentifiers:]
 - LSOpenApplication()
```

Until recently I thought I can rely on **-psn** argument sent by Finder when user manually launches the application. But this argument is sent on 10.8 even when MainApp is launched by HelperApp.

In the [article](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/) mentioned above, author suggests using `[NSWorkspace - launchApplicationAtURL: options: configuration: error:]`. Parameters are sent, but nothing arrives to the MainApp.

Has anyone succeeded to accomplish this (or similar) task?

Need help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hell of searching and experimenting I am ready to answer my own question, so others can save their time and efforts.

My conclusion is that for now there is no way HelperApp can launch MainApp with some arguments under the Sandbox. At least I have not found any way to do that.

Launch MainApp like this:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:newPath];
```

In MainApp add the following:

```
Application_IsLaunchedByHelperApp = YES;

ProcessSerialNumber currPSN;
OSStatus err = GetCurrentProcess(&currPSN);
if (!err)
{
    // Get information about our process
    NSDictionary * currDict = [(NSDictionary *)ProcessInformationCopyDictionary(&currPSN,
                                                                                kProcessDictionaryIncludeAllInformationMask) autorelease];

    // Get the PSN of the app that launched us. Its not really the parent app, in the unix sense.
    long long temp = [[currDict objectForKey:@"ParentPSN"] longLongValue];

    long long hi = (temp >> 32) & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFLL;
    long long lo = (temp >> 0) & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFLL;
    ProcessSerialNumber parentPSN = {(UInt32)hi, (UInt32)lo};

    // Get info on the launching process
    NSDictionary * parentDict = [(NSDictionary*)ProcessInformationCopyDictionary(&parentPSN,
                                                                                 kProcessDictionaryIncludeAllInformationMask) autorelease];

    // analyze
    // parent app info is not null ?
    if (parentDict && parentDict.count > 0)
    {
        NSString * launchedByAppBundleId = [parentDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
        if (![launchedByAppBundleId isEqualToString:HELPER_APP_BUNDLE_ID])
        {
            Application_IsLaunchedByHelperApp = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. `Application_IsLaunchedByHelperApp` now has correct value.

The solution is not mine. I've found it on the web (cocoabuilder, I guess). Good luck to everyone! And thanks for your attention to my questions.

**UPDATE**
Looks like there are cases when launched at login app shows `launchedByAppBundleId = @"com.apple.loginwindow"`. So the last part of code will look like this:

```
    //
    // analyze
    //

    // parent app info is not null ?
    if (parentDict && parentDict.count > 0)
    {
        NSString * launchedByAppBundleId = [parentDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
        if (![launchedByAppBundleId isEqualToString:HELPER_APP_BUNDLE_ID] &&
            ![launchedByAppBundleId isEqualToString:@"com.apple.loginwindow"])
        {
            Application_IsLaunchedByHelperApp = NO;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In fact I am surprised that Apple bringing the sandbox and forcing developers to switch to SMLoginItemSetEnabled to get 'LaunchAtStartup' feature, didn't provide any simple way to get notified about MainApp launch environment. Am I naive?

Comment: Naive? I'm cynical and am convinced that these days Apple's motto is "the customer/developer is always wrong" ;-) The reason for not passing arguments in the launch is given as a security risk. The "application groups" (if I've called it the right name) is the mechanism Apple subsequently introduced to allow multiple sandboxed applications to access a shared container, and given that I think you can build what you need. And others found other ways, they all are (or were...) covered somewhere in those forums... but finding things can be a challenge!

Comment: I read about 'application group', but if I remember correctly, you have to ask a special permission from Apple to create it, don't you?

Comment: I don't think so, let me Google... Look in the Entitlement Key Reference (google "Adding an App to an App Group"). Obviously your "group" will have to go through App Review, so toss coin ;-) I see there is an Apple demo AppSandboxLoginItemXPCDemo which uses an application group.

Comment: I would use NO as the default value for Application_IsLaunchedByHelperApp (and set it to YES only for explicit string match with launchedByAppBundleId), though it depends on the app.

Comment: You're right. But in my case it is more important to have YES when something goes wrong with checks :)

Answer (score 1):

The place to seek an answer is the Apple Developer Forums - folk there have dealt with all sorts of issues around helper apps and the sandbox. Searching for application groups and custom URL schemes going back, say, 1-2 years may turn up a solution that meets your needs. If you are still stuck post a question on those forums, someone will probably know what you need.

If you are not an Apple Developer so have no access to those forums, or do not intend to distribute via the Mac App Store, then just turn off the sandbox - in its current state this isn't technology you choose to use... HTH.

Comment: Thank you @CRD! I am an Apple Developer and targeting for the AppStore, so I will surely follow your hint. I will also write here if the solution is found. Meanwhile everyone willing to share the experience are all very welcome!